# Unable to run JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a function in JQuery run through calling it with two buttons.
The first button runs the function as expected and the second button calls the function used by the first button, however it's not working.

This is my code:

```
-----------------HTML-----------------

<button class="Original">Original</button>
<button class="Second">Second</button>

----------------JQuery----------------

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Original").click(function foo(){
        alert("bar");
    });

    $(".Second").click(function(){
        foo();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tRm3d/)

I am a newbie.Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Why don't you just have the function declaration outside of the click event handler?

Comment: This is just a small example of a bigger code, I've written tons of code already and changing it would take about an hour

Comment: Spend the time to do it right ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try simulating click of  $(".Original") on $(".Second") click

```
$(".Second").click(function(){
        $(".Original").click();
    });
```

foo() method is only delegated to $(".Original") click event, it is unknown outside.

here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRm3d/2/)

Comment: or, refactor providing a function "foo()" visible by both, and call it in both cases, e.g. `$(".Original").click(function(){
        foo();
    });`

Comment: Simulating the click of original will daisy-chain the events. That is possibly what the OP was looking for but to me it seems it would make more sense to properly scope the foo function.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents.

Not sure why you don't just have the function declaration outside of the event handler. e.g.

```
// declare the function
var foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
};

// bind click event handler for Original
$('.Original').click(foo);

// bind click event handler for Second
$('.Second').click(foo);

// call the function from anywhere
foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a function within another function.So you cannot call it directly.See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tRm3d/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Original").click(function foo(){
        alert("bar");
    });

    $(".Second").click(function(){
        $(".Original").click().foo();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

foo is declared inside of the first click event. It will not be scoped and available for the second.

See this JS fiddle for the correct way to scope this function: http://jsfiddle.net/tRm3d/4/

```
var function foo() {}
```

should be outside of the click events.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this? ;)

```
<button class="first">First</button>
<button class="second">Second</button>

$(function(){
    $( '.first, .second' ).on( 'click', function() {
        alert( 'You clicked me!' );
    });
});
```

Comment: I was trying to get the function to use two different buttons and call the function separately since what i'm trying to use doesn't have two buttons, instead it gets called by a calculation. Anyways thanks for the help tough